# triple integral over a shifted cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$D=\{(y−2)^2+x^2\le1,0≤z≤2\} $

I need to calculate the volume.

so I'ts a cylinder with radius 1, and shifted by 2 units in the y axe. The problem here is that the circle doesn't touch the origin! so in cylindrical coordinates $y$ should be $y=2+rsen(θ)$, is this correct ?

$\int_{-sin^{-1}{(1/\sqrt{5})}}^{sin^{-1}{(1/\sqrt{5})}}\int_{1}^{2sin\theta+1/2(\sqrt{16sin^2\theta-12})}\int_{0}^{2}rdzdrd\theta$

Is this theoretically right?

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to calculate it using a triple integral? Why not with base-area$\times$ height?

Comment: Yes with triple integral. I'm just curious :P

Comment: What does it means $.... =1\le 0$  ?

Comment: I fixed it , yeah

Comment: For the purpose of this exercise (which I must confess I don't see the point of), you can forget the $z$-coordinate, can't you? It becomes the problem of finding the area of a circle using polar coordinates.

Comment: I'm just curious on how to parametrize a circle which is not tangent to any axes. and find how the radius is connected to the angle $\theta$.  this problem could be used for example to find the flux through this surface (with vector field like F(x,y,z)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use a triple integral than note that, since we don't have a cylindrical symmetry, the use of cylindrical coordinates is not the best choice.

It is simpler to use Cartesian coordinates, noting that:
$$
-\sqrt{1-(y-2)^2}\le x \le \sqrt{1-(y-2)^2}
$$

for:  $1\le y\le3$

so the integral is:
$$
\int_1^3\int_{-\sqrt{1-(y-2)^2}}^{\sqrt{1-(y-2)^2}}\int_0^2 dzdxdy
$$

Comment: yeah, sure! but I just want to see how to do it in cylindrical coordinates, I'm just curious how to parametrize a shifted cylinder integrating it